# Selenium IDE blocks page content on latest Firefox version

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

My team and I have been experiencing an odd issue with Selenium IDE and the latest Firefox versions (19, 20) recently. Our Selenium IDE script clicks on a button to open a new page window but the expected page content is missing. If we close the Selenium IDE interface (since it is open during the script execution) and click to open the new page the expected content appears. We reverted the Firefox version down to 14 and have noticed this issue doesn't occur.

In other words, having the Selenium IDE interface open during the script execution affects the content display in some pages when using the latest Firefox browser.

So far our research has been futile. Anyone has experienced a similar problem and found a solution?

Comment: I'd suggest creating a new issue on [Selenium's bug tracker](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/list) if there isn't one already exists.

Comment: Is this issue still occuring ? I'm using Firefox 29.0 and have experience no issue like that with Selenium IDE